# Where can I find shapefile (free/open source) for all countries at Admin 2/3 level

Tags: data

I need to download shapefiles for all country from which I need to generate TopoJSON for around all countries.

Currently I am using data from naturalearthdata.org which only provides Admin levels 0 and 1 for all countries. I need for Admin levels 2 and 3 which covers towns/cities/districts details.

I have tried diva-gis.org I had to download country by country from drop down which is taking lot of time.

Is there any site I can download shapefile for admin 2,3 for all countries as single shapefile or country specific shapefiles. (free/open source)

I will integrate this map/ TopoJSON inside d3.js /Java /j2ee project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with OpenStreetMap and convert it to shapefile or directly look for one shapefile source:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles#Obtaining_shapefiles_from_OSM_data

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative to Natural Earth is the Database of Global Administrative Areas (GADM):  https://gadm.org/download_world.html. It is continuously updated and provides a much higher resolution.